# Getting data from remote server and screen orientation issue in tablet

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

What I expected in my application is data coming from the server and everything, even the view, are dynamically created. The activity layout is divided into two parts. On the left is a list and on the right side are dynamic fragment changes. Whenever the orientation changes the server call is made again (As the activity is destroyed and re-created). This is working fine.
There are 3 fragments(2 are Maps) that have to be called from inside of each other on the right side of the layout.

Now I dont want this thing to happen. I don't want everything to refresh again and start from scratch.

I can't set configChange in the manifest, as the image sizes in the layout for landscape and portrait are somewhat different.

What is needed is a layout change on orientation change without re-creating the activity.

I have tried using onSaveInstanceState() and onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is to set the configChange on your manifest AND create different layouts for portrait and landscape so you can have the results you are expecting: No refresh of the activity, and control the sizes of your ImageViews.